# Web app design questions - RoR 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is my first web app that i am developing and i have some design questions, i have a few book about RoR3 but i dont seem to find answers to my questions.
My application is based on Ruby on rails 3

I am not looking for detailed answers here, if you can just point me to a topic name that i could learn about that can answer my qustions, such as "names resources" , "hidden fields" .....

My questions:
1- How to send information between View A and controller B. Example, i am on the View for "Company" when i click create employee i am calling the "new view" for the employee so i am now on a different view, how can i pass to the new employee  action the ID of the company? Since i am now on a different view ? i don’t want to use nested resources
What are the different ways to send information across different controllers/views

2- ruby URLs: i can view am item in my model via the URL: http://localhost:3000/Companies/1
I don’t want the url to contain the index of the item, each company has a name and i want to display this name in the url such as   http://localhost:3000/Companies/myCompany
How can i change the url structure of rails?

Comment: There can be a lot to talk about your question. This is not an aswer to your questions, but a suggestion. I would definetly recommend reading the rails guides from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ ; It contains every bit of information you request at a beginner level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you can pass the parameters with the link (assuming you have employee and company variables accessible to your view):

**Edit**: this should work:

```
= link_to "create employee", :controller => "employees", :action => "new", :company_id => @company.id
```

And in the `Employees` controller:

```
def new
  company_id = params[:company_id]
  # check that company_id is not nil before doing stuff with it
end
```

I'm not sure why doing this ignores any extra parameters:

```
= link_to "create employee", new_employee_path, :company_id => @company.id
```

For your second question, [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you Johnny, you answered my second question. As for the first one, it seems that null is always being passed. i am on the show view of company and i can display the company_id on that show page so it is not null, my <%= link_to "create employee", new_employee_path, :company_id => @company.id %> is failing because it seems that it is passed as null, so i can not save my employee. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a fix. I'm curious to know why it doesn't work the original way though.

Comment: Thank you, this totally works. I am not sure why the first solution is ignoring tha parameters though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass the company id as parameters at create employee link .

In the controller ,receive the params like
def new 
  company_id = params[:company_id]
....
end

2. For using some string instead of id , use gem 'friendly_id'
   Make sure your reference string should be unique.